# Display vector as rows instead of columns in Octave

Tags: vector, octave, transpose, output-formatting

I'm new to octave and running into a formatting issue which I can't seem to fix. If I display a variable with multiple columns I get something along the lines of:

```
Columns 1 through 6:

        0.75883  0.93290  0.40064  0.43818  0.94958  0.16467
```

However what I would really like to have is:

```
0.75883  
0.93290  
0.40064  
0.43818
0.94958
0.16467
```

I've read the format documentation [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Terminal-Output.html#doc-format) but haven't been able to make the change. I'm running Octave 3.6.4 on Windows however I've used Octave 3.2.x on Windows and seen it output to the desired output by default.

To be specific, in case it matters, I am using the fir1 command as part of the signal package and these are sample outputs that I might see.

Comment: So you just want to display the transpose?

Comment: Yup, that was it. Thanks. I'm still curious as to why the fir1 command is 1xn on one system and nx1 on another but this will work just fine.

Comment: IF you call `A(:)` you guarantee it to be nx1 whereas with `A'` you're uncertain what you'll get as it depends on `A`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like, as Dan suggested, you want to display the transpose of your vector, i.e. a row vector rather than a column vector:

```
>> A = rand(1,20)
A =

 Columns 1 through 7:

   0.681499   0.093300   0.490087   0.666367   0.212268   0.456260   0.532721

 Columns 8 through 14:

   0.850320   0.117698   0.567046   0.405096   0.333689   0.179495   0.942469

 Columns 15 through 20:

   0.431966   0.100049   0.650319   0.459100   0.613030   0.779297

>> A'
ans =

   0.681499
   0.093300
   0.490087
   0.666367
   0.212268
   0.456260
   0.532721
   0.850320
   0.117698
   0.567046
   0.405096
   0.333689
   0.179495
   0.942469
   0.431966
   0.100049
   0.650319
   0.459100
   0.613030
   0.779297
```